# Fileupload and form, posting one extra time for each request in UI dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm struggeling with a form that are beeing posted one extra time per request. I'm using the jquery fileupload inside of a dialog.

What I belive is the case is that the click event are beeing added one extra time per upload. But I dont want the form to remember this, and I'm using the "destroy" function on dialog close..

The submit code:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
     url: 'fileupload.aspx',
     add: function (e, data) {
         $("#upload").live("click", function (ev) {
             data.submit();
         });
     },
     formData: function () {
         return $('#myform').serializeArray();
     },
     maxNumberOfFiles: 1,
     replaceFileInput: false,
     dataType: 'json',

     done: function (e, data) {
         $('#myform')[0].reset();

         $('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').click();
     }
 });
```

Comment: When did u call this file upload either in document ready or after dialog opens

Comment: Its beeing called when opening the dialog. The script is inside the file that is opened.

Answer (score 0):

Is `#fileupload` part of `#myform`? If so, `$('#myform').serializeArray()` includes that element, so the file is being sent as additional data along with the fileupload.